# Ruby on Rails | Collection_Select [Value] -> Param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Got a (hopefully) easy one:

Ruby partial view with a collection_select, need the value of that selection (var name = 'submod') passed as a param up to controller. Literally just stuck on how to get from collection_select/onchange() to named param.

html.erb code:

```
<% @modName = locals[:moduleName] %>
<% @id = locals[:id] %>

<%= form_with url: admin_command_path() do |f| %>
    <%= collection_select(@refcode, :Code, Command.where(FLD: @modName), :Code, :Definition, options ={prompt: true}, html_options = {:onchange => "updateSubMod(this.value)"}) %>
    <br /><br />
    <button class="btn_new">
        <%= link_to "Execute", new_admin_command_path(mod: @modName, submod: @refcode, id: @id) %>
    </button>
<% end %>
```

The onchange function works as expected, so feel free to make use of that to solve for param:

```
<script>
    function updateSubMod(Code) {
        var submod = Code
        console.log(submod, '********************')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Rails AJAX will do it for you: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/

Comment: Or if you want to go cutting edge with Rails 7, check out Hotwire.

Comment: Thanks Chip! I confess, I was hoping to avoid Ajax, for whatever reason it's a pain to redeploy, but thank you! I had not heard of Hotwire, and we're still using Rails 4 lol, but I will check it out!

Comment: Once you have AJAX implemented, be sure to post an answer here and select it as the solution.